# What is 500 internal Server Error?

Tags: internal-server-error

I got error like 500 internal Server Error,

```
function getRoleList() {
        queryString = '';
        $http.post($postDomain + '/tile/getRoles' + queryString).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.roles = data.Listdata;
        }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // log error
        });
    }
```

In my above function not post $http.post($postDomain + '/tile/getRoles' + queryString), I am checked that url showing correct but not going that url,Why? I  changed my File permission 755 and also i delete and upolad new htaccess file?Whats wrong i do file permission or my htaccess file.

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Htaccess file code.Anything wrong in my code?But Same file in my localhost its working fine but i moved to server it got error like these?

Comment: look into the Server logfiles and you should see the erro message

Comment: ya got it thanx,but  i have one doubt in my issue $m =  [];
        foreach($listData as $a){
            $status = $curSkill == $a['id'] ? true : false;
            $m[] = array('id'=>$a['id'],'skill_name'=> $a['skill_name'],'active'=>$status);
        } $m =  []; is working in localhost but its showing error in my server why? $m = [] is declare incorrect?why its showing error?

Comment: Maybe different php Versions?

Comment: Now i used $m =array(); My Declaration is correct? jens.